# Where do those nasty red balls (eggs?) come from in Darwinia?

Tags: darwinia

Two questions, really:

- Does the game explain at some point where those red "eggs" come from?
- Where does these red "eggs" come from?

Comment: I don't agree with that cypher thingy

Comment: Yeah, just add a `spoilers` tag to the question. If you don't want spoilers, you won't want to see the answers anyway, and therefore won't click the question.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't want to read the full story just yet as I hadn't yet finished the game... Hence why I split the answer in two parts, does the game tell you (is it a spoiler in the first place?) and the spoily part itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The eggs are being spit by the flower-like things. You can destroy the flowers.

Also, the big slow flying monsters ("Spore Generators") lay them.

Comment: The flower-like things are called triffids.

Answer (score 1):

All the red stuff is either a virus, or something infected by it (in the case of red darwinians)

[Here](http://www.brighthub.com/video-games/pc/articles/68346.aspx)'s an enemy guide I found

Answer (score 0):

Like everything else, they are created by the virus.

They are some sort of "plant" that drop them where they detect your activity.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your first question: no, the game won't explain about the origin of the eggs. But it *will* explain the origin of virus in the end - but I don't want to spoil it for you, let's just say I liked it